# Add custom Pass to Apple Wallet

Tags: ios, passkit, apple-wallet

I want to add simple card/coupon to the Apple Wallet by the iOS app which one will only contains only logo/name of my app and deeplink to specific screen in my app(without bar codes, card number and stuff). I saw some image examples and also my local grocery store has it, where there is small button in right-left corner which one can handle this.

Is it posible to make larger button than in examples or at least I can add some clickable text with deeplink on pass/card. Could somebody provides example of the .json file with this type of button with icon in it?

[image: Button example]